# How to determine if mapped route is being used in ASP.NET MVC solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on the route configuration of a solution that previously had many unnecessary calls to `RouteCollection.MapRoute()` which essentially could all be replaced with a default route by merely changing the ActionResult methods a little.  Now I'm down to just one route besides the default and I'm having a hard time telling if it's being used anywhere in the solution.  The code now looks like this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{directory}/{resource}.asmx/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",  
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);

routes.MapRoute("GridPaging", "{controller}/{action}/{page}", null);
```

The variable `routes` is an instance of `RouteCollection`.  So, is there some way I can determine if the GridPaging route is actually being used anywhere?  As an aside, Visual Studio indicates that the overload being used for that call to MapRoute is [the one where the fourth parameter is the string array of namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492682(v=vs.100).aspx).  I'm not sure how it decides on that signature given the null argument could [supposably](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supposably) resolve to [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505187(v=vs.100).aspx) as well.

Comment: If search by "GridPaging" through the project does not give you any results, you can be 100% sure the route is not used. Routing works on "first route to fit" basis, and default route completely shadows the other one. So if there is no usage by route name, there is no usage at all

Comment: Perhaps look for a grid with paging and investigate exactly how it performs paging.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a definitive way to test if a route is being hit for a specific url, but I can tell you that with your current configuration, any url for for the GridPaging route will also match default and use the default route instead. You should place any custom routes before the default route because routes are matched in the order that you add them to the collection. You can read the docs on [ASP.NET routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#how_urls_are_matched_to_routes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"GridPaging" is a route name, so searching for "GridPaging" in your code should tell you where this route is used.

If you would like to see more which route is called you can install and use [Route Debugger](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebApiRouteDebugger/) from NuGet.

[Here is a link on how to use Route Debugger](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/04/04/debugging-asp-net-web-api-with-route-debugger.aspx)

EDIT:

If you are using ASP.NET MVC you can get [ASP.NET MVC Routing Debugger Visualizer](https://mvcroutevisualizer.codeplex.com/)

Comment: The linked blog post talks about Web API and mentions using Areas.  Can this tool be used with MVC and in a solution that does not use Areas?

Comment: Sorry, I have not noticed that you are using ASP.NET MVC. For ASP.NET MVC you can use ASP.NET MVC Routing Debugger Visualizer https://mvcroutevisualizer.codeplex.com/

Comment: The tools for Web API and MVC mentioned in this answer and comments should be sufficient for most route debugging needs on the .Net platform.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Phill's post [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/30/introducing-routemagic.aspx/) and find witch route your app is using.

The way your routes are configured, you only get the GridPaging route if you use RouteName, with default route resolution you'll get on Default route because they essentially has the same path.

Comment: I found Phil's posts interesting, but didn't figure out how to use them to debug routes.  I was the one who added the default route, so to avoid breaking the GridPaging route, in case it is being used, I moved it to the top until I can get a chance to properly analyze it with the tools mentioned by Vlad.